# Ping through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ping

I'm kinda new to this whole node super framework and I wanna know if there is any library-sub framework-package-whatever that lets you ping from the users end to a server through a nodejs web app and let's you get back all the available ping options like Time to live, do fragment, delay etc.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326609/ping-through-nodejs/41330150#41330150) below help you? Any comments? If so then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646) so other people who search it could see that it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following modules on npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping

Remember that for ping you need a raw socket and usually root access so your only choice is to use a Node wrapper of a suid binary, or running your Node app as root or with sudo.

Comment: Thank you. Running an app as root user will be an issue in specific environments.  Are you aware of any other alternative to check Internet connection without give root priviledges? @rsp